# Show content with a date after the current one on a view

Tags: 7, views, input-formats, datetime

I'm creating a calendar of events with Drupal 7 using views. At the moment the elements are shown in order of the date of each one (I have a date field where I put the date of the event). Now I need that when the date is passed, it does not appear anymore.

For example, if I have an event that was held yesterday, today it would not have to appear in the view.

Thank you!

[image: Filter criteria on views]

[image: and this is de field type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a filter based on the date field and the criteria should be "**greater than or equal to**", then select "**Enter a relative date**" in the drop down field and enter the word "**now**"

Here is a screenshot from a site that has a Register By date field and I have a list of Upcoming Events that show based on this in a homepage block.

[image]

Comment: Hello Travis, thanks for your answer but in the date field filter criteria I don't have this option. I have a "Operator" select and "greather than or equal to" is not in this select, and a input with the label value... So I can't find the "Enter a relative date" option. Maybe I have to install a module?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Date Filter options? You don't need an extra module for this. Are you sure it's a Date field you created?

Comment: Sure thing Berta, image added.

Comment: hello! thanks for all, i have added two images: The filter criteria configuration on view screenshoot and a row where you can see the field type..  I don't know why I can't see this options

Comment: OWCH! Sorry, thanks for all! I just discovered that I had the "Date_views" module disabled